# Can we use Firebase in iOS apps designed for kids?

Tags: ios, firebase

App Store guidelines state,

> Apps in the Kids Category should not include third-party analytics or
>   third-party advertising.

Can we use other Firebase features like authentication, database excluding Firebase analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Authentication and Firebase database offerings are not considered analytics products that track user behavior or provide advertising.

Formally, you should consult a lawyer to know for sure if your use of Firebase is considered lawful for the purpose of App Store guidelines.  I am not a lawyer, but personally, I do not see a problem with it.